# QRegExp and colon after string

Tags: regex, qt, qregexp

I have a problem with QRegExp. This is my source. I would like both the `"Re:"` and `"Fwd:"` substrings to be deleted:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QRegExp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QString s = "Fwd: Re: my subject line";
    cout << "original string: " << s.toLatin1().data() << endl;

    QRegExp rx("\\b(Re:|Fwd:)\\b");
    rx.setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);

    s.replace(rx,"");
    cout << "replaced string: " << s.toLatin1().data() << endl;

}
```

It doesn't works. The output:

```
original string: Fwd: Re: my subject line
replaced string: Fwd: Re: my subject line
```

If I remove the `':'` character in the RegExp, the substrings `"Re"` and `"Fwd"` will be deleted, but `':'` character remains into text.

How I an set the regexp expression to delete both `"Re:"` and `"Fwd:"` substrings from text?

Answer (score 2):

```
QRegExp rx("\\b(Re:|Fwd:)\\b");
```

`\b` only works with `\w` type, so you can actually write

```
QRegExp rx("\\b(Re:|Fwd:)");
```

or

```
QRegExp rx("(Re:|Fwd:)");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

```
QString s = "Fwd: Re: Re: my subject: line";
cout << "original string: " << s.toLatin1().data() << endl;

QRegExp rx("\\b(Re|Fwd)\\b[:]");
rx.setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);

s.replace(rx,"");
s = s.trimmed();
cout << "replaced string: " << s.toLatin1().data() << endl;
```

and the output is:

```
original string: Fwd: Re: Re: my subject: line
replaced string: my subject: line
```